# Error 3001 vba Excel Macros MySQL Insert

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

Im trying to insert a row in a mysql db using Excel Macros. The connection appears to be working OK but i get a vba 3001 error

(Microsoft visual basic 3001 arguments are of the wrong type, or are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another)

when y execute this code:

```
        Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        ConnectDB           
       'strSQL = "INSERT INTO talar.ots (UbicacionTecnica, Equipo, Posmant) VALUES ('sdasd', 'sdasd','sdasd')"

        rs.Open strSQL, oConn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
```

I allready read and try different things with 50 tutorials and other posts in this page, all bad results....

this is the code of the connection:

```
    Private Sub ConnectDB()
    Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=localhost;" & _
    "DATABASE=talar;" & _
    "USER=root;" & _
    "PASSWORD=root;" & _
    "Option=3"
     End Sub
```

MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver is installed, mysql service is running fine, I am using Excel 2010, windows 7. I dont know if this information is enough.
anyone have any idea?
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oConn` is *local* to the `ConnectDB` sub so you are passing nothing to the recordsets `Open`.

Add `Option Explicit` to the top of your code file to receive a warning when you do something like this.

Make a function that returns the connection:

```
Private Function ConnectDB() As ADODB.Connection
    Set ConnectDB = New ADODB.Connection
    ConnectDB.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.2 Unicode Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=talar;USER=root;PASSWORD=root;Option=3"
End Function
```

Then

```
dim cn as ADODB.Connection
set cn = ConnectDB()           

cn.Execute "INSERT INTO talar.ots (UbicacionTecnica, Equipo, Posmant) VALUES ('sdasd', 'sdasd','sdasd')"

cn.Close
```

You do not need a `Recordset` for an insert as no rows will be returned.

When you do need a `Recordset` `adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly` are better than `adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic` unless you specifically need the features offered by the latter.